# Abnormal value of ROC AUC score in Binary Classifier Model

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, python-3.x

I have developed the following model for a Binary Classifier. I have to evluate using `roc_auc_score`. I am getting unusual values for `roc_auc_score`.

When I use
`epoch = 1, roc_auc_score = 0.8`
`epoch = 2,  roc_auc_score =0.53`

And after this for any epoch it is constant at 0.5. Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my model?

**DATA PREPROCESSING**

```
#Load Dataset
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

#Combine Train and Test set for Data Cleaning
train['set'] = 'train'
test['set'] = 'test'
df = pd.concat([test, train])

#One Hot Encoding
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Gender','Driving_License','Previously_Insured','Vehicle_Age','Vehicle_Damage'])

#Moving Target Column to End
target = df['Response']
df.drop(labels=['Response'], axis=1, inplace = True)
df.insert(16, 'Response', target)

#Separating Train and Test Data
train = df[df['set']=='train']
test = df[df['set']=='test']
train = train.drop('set', 1)
test = test.drop('set', 1)

#Creating Input Features and Target Variables
X= train.iloc[:,1:15]
y= train.iloc[:,[15]]

#Standardizing the Input Features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

#Train Test Split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
```

**CODE**

```
#Model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(14, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', input_dim=14))
  
#Output Layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

#Compiling the neural network
model.compile(optimizer ='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])

#Fitting the data to the training dataset  
model.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1, verbose=0) 

#Make predictions and convert to binary value
pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
pred_test = model.predict(X_test)  

#ROC AUC Score
print('Train AUC = {:.5f}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_train,pred_train)))
print('Test AUC = {:.5f}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_test,pred_test)))

#Accuracy
print('Train Accuracy = {:.3f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_train,pred_train.round())))
print('Test Accuracy = {:.3f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test,pred_test.round())))
```

Comment: Are those roc_auc_scores measured on train or test? If it's train, it's very strange, cos the code looks fine. Maybe you've preprocessed you data somehow incorrectly.

Comment: roc_auc_score is same for both datasets form epoch=2. Should I add my data preprocessing?

Comment: Well, the problem maybe somewhere there. If that code isn't difficult to read, I can glance

Comment: @MichaelSolotky I have added the data preprocessing, it's fairly simple. First I have combined the train and test set, then performed one hot encoding on required features and then again separated train and test set. Just to mention performing Data Standardization also gave the same result.

Comment: Why only 1 layer. Have you tried with 5-6 layers

Comment: @10xAI Yes I tried multiple layers as well as dropouts, but they were giving the same result from epoch = 2 and they were causing the result of epoch = 1 to degrade.

Comment: Tried different (esp. smaller) learning rates?

Comment: @BenReiniger I tried with smaller learning rate(as small as 0.00001) but no difference.

Comment: I'd try shuffling the data. As in put some test data in training set and training data in test set. Then train and test and see if it still happens.